# Php array of arrays to json in loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am new in php, please help with my code.

I am trying to create PHP json for IOS app. Json should looks like this

```
{"items": [
    {
        "ID":12, 
        "name1":"some name",
        "name2":"some name2"            
    },
    {
        "ID":13,
        "name1":"another name",
        "name2":"another name2"
    },] }
```

Here is my PHP code part

```
$keys = array(ID, name1, name2);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
extract($row);
$values = array($row['ID'], $row['name1'], $row['name2']);
$response = array_combine($keys, $values);
header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

This gives me result like this

```
 {
        "ID":12, 
        "name1":"some name",
        "name2":"some name2"            
    }
    {
        "ID":13,
        "name1":"another name",
        "name2":"another name2"
    }
```

Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're almost there. The result you have is an array. The result you want is a JSON object with an `Items` property that contains that array.

Comment: You might be better asking for assistance in SO chat -https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php as that is a much better forum for code review and discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build your array, and then encode the JSON outside of the loop for a start;

```
$keys = array(ID, name1, name2);
$items = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    extract($row);
    $values = array($row['ID'], $row['name1'], $row['name2']);
    $item = array_combine($keys, $values);
    $items[] = $item;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array("items"=>$items), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Here we build up an array of your items into `$items`, and then encode them all outside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does exactly what I need. I was searching for solution about 3 days )))

Comment: It's always easy when you know how!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are new or really don't know something about json yet

but i'll try to help you

just simply stored it in associative array an assign `items` as it's index

```
   $response = array(
      'items' => array_combine($keys, $values)
   );
   header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8');
   echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I json is really new for me. 
You suggestion gives me almost same result :( 

{"items":{"ID":"15","name1":"some name","name2":"some name2"}}{"items":{"ID":"16","name1":"another name","name2":"another name2"}}